# How to reboot my Raspberry Pi after wrong edition of my fstab?

Tags: boot, boot-issues, fstab

I edited my `fstab` file (`/etc/fstab`) to mount a new `/media` local network drive.

After this wrong edition, my Raspberry eventually can't boot anymore. I get the error:

```
Cannot open access to console, the root account is locked.
See sulogin(8) man page for more details.
```

My aim is to edit the `fstab` to correct the mistake and get my Pi bootable again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since I found the solution myself, I am posting it here, very grateful to every author of the raspberry pi forum posts.

### 1. Part 1 - getting command line in the boot

**Error**

Got `"Cannot open access to console, the root account is locked."` error.

**Solution**

- Mount the SDCard on another computer (any type).
- *Tip:* if you don't have a SDCard reader on your computer, use your smartphone.
- In the FAT32 `/boot` partition (which should be accessible in Windows for instance), there is a file called `cmdline.txt`. I appended `init=/bin/bash` to that file.
- Now, my Raspberry Pi boot with a root access command line.

### 2. Part 2 - remount with the commmand line

**Error**

- I tried to edit directly with `nano /etc/fstab`
- But I get an error `mount: can't find PARTUUID=f2d3cb4f-02.`
- I tried to mount the partition in rewrite mode with `mount -o remount,rw /` but I still got the fstab error

**Solution**

- Remount partially only one mounting point with `sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/mmcblk0p2 /`
- Edit the `fstab` file to fix the mistake
- Use your other computer to remove the `init=/bin/bash` from the `cmdline.txt`
- Reboot your Raspberry Pi
- Tada!

### Sources

Many thanks to:

- https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=221744
- https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=172814
- https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=193153

Comment: Why do not edit `etc/fstab` direct on your other computer?

Comment: on windows, I cannot access the right partition, so I couldn't edit the file. I could if I had a Linux or (probably) MacOS

Comment: mac doesn't support ext4, and also when I try adding that line it ends up with a kernel panic saying that I tried to kill the `init` process

Comment: for me it fixed running first `umount /` and then `mount -o remount,rw /dev/mmcblk0p2 / `

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't use @jmax's answer because for some reason I couldn't ever get into the command line. Maybe it's a mac thing?

For anyone that hits this problem that only has a mac, you can install this software and use the free 10-day trial to mount the sd card on your mac and just edit the `/etc/fstab` file directly.

https://www.paragon-drivers.com/en/extfsmac/

It's not free software though so just don't mess up your fstab again ;)